# How to use namespace System in a managed c++ reference class

Tags: c++-cli

I am trying to create managed C++ class by following this tutorial [msdn.microsoft.com](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke3a209d.aspx) But while i tried to use namespace System **System::String *_msg** it always gives me an error that says

> An ordinary pointer to a C++/Cli ref class or interface class is not
>   allowed

**Hello.h**

```
using namespace System;
ref class Hello
{

public:
    System::String *_msg;
    Hello(System::String *Msg);
};
```

**hello.cpp File**

```
#include "Hello.h"
using namespace System;


Hello::Hello(System::String *Msg)
{
    Msg = _msg;
    Console::WriteLine(Msg);
}
void main() {
    Hello ^ h = gcnew Hello("hello world");

}
```

Comment: Why not make it a managed pointer (^) ? From what i understand, System::String is a ref class and you cannot use normal pointers with that.

Comment: Use managed pointer/handle `^` with managed code and ref classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of unmanaged `*` pointer use the managed pointer `^` sign:

```
using namespace System;

    ref class Hello
    {
    public:
        System::String ^_msg;
        Hello(System::String ^Msg);
    };
    #include "Hello.h"
    using namespace System;

    Hello::Hello(System::String ^Msg)
    {
        Msg = _msg;
        Console::WriteLine(Msg);
    }
    void main() {
        Hello ^ h = gcnew Hello("hello world");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for faster response.